# How to call public variables of a used module through a module with private statement

Tags: fortran

In my Fortran code I define variables in modules and I use them from the main program with a `USE` statement.
To limit access the the content of my modules, by default I declare all variables/functions/subroutines as `private` and then declare specifically which of them are public.

This works well when I want to access to the variables/functions/subroutines of a module I use in my main program, however when a module `mod1` uses another module `mod2`, it seems that all the variables/functions/subroutines of `mod2` become private to `mod1` and cannot be accessed from the main program.

What is the keyword to keep my public declarations in `mod2` public, so that I can access them from the main program ?

Here is a minimum working example of my problem

**main.f90**

```
program main
use mod1
implicit none
print*,publicvar
end program main
```

**mod1.f90**

```
module mod1
use mod2
private
end module mod1
```

**mod2.f90**

```
module mod2
private
integer, parameter, public :: publicvar = 1
end module mod2
```

To run the example:

```
>ifort mod2.f90 mod1.f90 main.f90 -o main
main.f90(6): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PUBLICVAR]
  print*,publicvar
---------^
```

It works if I remove the `private` statement in `mod1`, but this is not acceptable for me as I want to keep by default all my variables/functions/subroutines private in the module.

Comment: I can understand why some people us the unfortunate tag [tag:fortran90], but in a question about submodules? Seriously?

Comment: @VladimirF Although the title says "submodules", it doesn't seem to me that the question is about them.  I've edited (hopefully Mazmike will confirm I'm correct) the title.

Comment: As well as the answer by IanH, you could consider: having the default accessibility in `mod1` as public, and explicitly having its entities private; using `mod2` in the main program.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PUBLIC statement in `mod1` to mark the things that are use associated from `mod2` to be public entities of `mod1`.

```
module mod1
  use mod2
  private
  public :: publicvar   ! from mod2
end module mod1
```

Comment: Thanks IanH. Your solution works but any addition of a public variable in `mod2` must be accompanied by a modification of mod1. It might become fastidious to use for a big code (consider the addition of multiple variables in `mod10`, used by `mod9`, used by... up to `mod1`.
I was wondering if there was another solution where you do not need to declare explicitly as public all your variables of interest.

Comment: Not in current Fortran, unless you remove the private statement in `mod`.  The next revision of the standard may contain such a facility.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I finally used your method, also recommended by francescalus. I keep waiting for a possible inclusion of this new facility in a revision of the standard, as a general definition of variables as private by default and explicitely declaring public variable seems to be a better programming rule to me.